# ACMの認証メールをGoogle suiteで紐付けたドメインメールに送りたいです。

Tags: aws

ドメインはお名前.comで取得をし、
Google suite でドメインとメールを紐付けました。

現状作っているアカウントは次の3つです。

```
support@your_domain
developer@youer_domain
myname@youer_domain
```

その上で、AWSのACMを用いて、SSLの発行をしたかったのですが、以下のメールアドレスにしか送信されないみたく、別途アカウントを作らないといけないということを知りました。

```
administrator@your_domain
admin@your_domain
hostmaster@your_domain
postmaster@your_domain
webmaster@your_domain
```

勿論、adminのアカウントを追加で作成すれば、この件は解決するのですが、
今後、別のプロジェクトでもGoogle suiteを使おうと思っていたため、このためだけにアカウントを追加し、さらには追加したことによる、料金も払わなくてはいけないため、より良い解決方法があればと思い質問しました。

また、別の方法としてSESを使うという方法もあり、今回はこちらを使うことで、SSLの取得はできております。
ただ、今後の作業効率化のためにも、Google suiteを使い、かつ、良い解決方法がありましたら是非ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G-Suiteではエイリアスとして受信専用のアドレスをユーザー辺り30まで割り当てることが可能です。

[G Suite でメール エイリアスを追加、削除する - G Suite 管理者 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=ja)

複数人に送信する場合は転送設定がいるかもしれませんが、とりあえず誰か1人が受信できればいいというなら上記リンク先に沿って操作すれば手っ取り早く用がたせます。

試しに ユーザー名「webmaster」でエイリアスを設定したところ、無事ACMの認証メールを受け取れました。

[image: エイリアス]
[image: メール]